# Analog of the -y flag in curl

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I have command:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

that gives following output:

```
.
.
.
.
Current installation options:


   default host triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
     default toolchain: stable (default)
               profile: default
  modify PATH variable: yes

1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation
```

It turns out that I have to type '1' into the terminal for the installation to continue. How can I change the command so that I don't have to enter '1' after initializing the command?

I poked around in the curl documentation but couldn't find a flag that could help me. Any ideas?

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `... https://sh.rustup.rs | sh` .. This is piping a program into your local `/bin/sh`. The best you can do is to download the file, modify the `switch case` (or what ever the `.rs` equivalent). and then run `sh sh.rustup.rs` locally. You might be able to make a `sed` filter that modifies the script while it being piped, but your exact use-case may not allow/require that. (And neither of these ideas are probably what you had in mind). Good luck!

Comment: So, this is not really  a `curl` issue, it is the method that the software publishers have chosen to program their install system. Good luck.